# rails sum Active Record Association Relation by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have `Foo::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` and I when I run this code in the console on that relation:

```
.inject(0){|sum,x| x.dimension == dimension && x.dimension_value == dimension_value && x.metric == metric ? (sum += x.metric_value) : ()}
```

I get the expected summed value it should return.

However when I added this code to the model

```
def self.sum_by(dimension, dimension_value, metric)
...
end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `inject' for #<Class:0x000000094cbbd0>
```

How do I apply that code correctly? Given that `Foo` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` I thought it should work.

Comment: Are you sure you can't express that as a `where` clause and use `sum` on it?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are removing the leading period when you copy it into a class.

However, inject is not a method on an ActiveRecord::Base object. It is from the Enumerable module, so you'd need to call it on something that has the enumerable module mixed in.

For instance, if you were trying to sum every instance of Foo, you could call Foo.all first, returning an array of all objects. so your code would look as follows.

```
def self.sum_by(dimension, dimension_value, metric)
  Foo.all.inject(0){|sum, a_foo| foo.dimension == dimension && foo.dimension_value == dimension_value && foo.metric == metric ? (sum += foo.metric_value) : ()}
end
```

Comment: I actually changed it to `scope :sum_by, -> (dimension, dimension_value, metric) {where(dimension: dimension, dimension_value: dimension_value, metric: metric).sum(:metric_value)}` but yours works fine too. Thanks!